# Scrolling Recyclerview should cover the Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android

I need a Toolbar with some height to stick at top. below it there is a Recycler-view. When this recycler-view is scrolled, it should cover the Toolbar and when scrolling back down, the toolbar appears. In short toolbar is behind the recycler-view when scrolling.

I saw collapsing toolbar and more option with coordinator layout. but that is actually the collapsing of toolbar or Swiping away the toolbar. I need the toolbar should be there only, but recycler-view when scrolled should cover it. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to achieve this using `FrameLayout` , framelayout allows elements inside of it to overlap, the last element of your xml will overlap the element on top of it, if they are not properly spaced.

You can place your toolbar on top and the recyclerview on bottom of it. If you add a `topMargin` with the size of your toolbar to your RV the toolbar would still appear on top, because the RV scrolls it's elements inside, to solve this add a `topPadding` with the size of your toolbar(using the propriety `?actionBarSize`), and give your RV a transparent background, and of course you need to add `android:clipToPadding="false"` to the RV.

This way your toolbar will appear behind. Now depending on your RV items you may need to set some background for them in order for your toolbar to not show behind.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/searchResultProductsRecyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/product"
        />
```

[image: a picture to clarify the answer]

Comment: I did this. I gave top padding to my recyclerview and clipTopPadding false also. but it was still scrolling behind the toolbar.

However my RV was inside the swipeRefereshLayout. Could that be a problem?

Comment: I am not sure, i have not worked with swipeRefreshLayout before, can you share your code

Comment: Many thanks for help. The problem was Swipe referesh only. I have managed to do it.

Comment: :- With this, the toolbar is not clickable anymore. May be because it is behind the recyclerview? Any help with this?